# mysql.socket dismissed, hope to recreate

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat

I ocassionally remove the file mysql.socket 
at /var/lib/mysql

thus the mysql can not start. Is it possible to recreate the file mysql.socket using command line? (my os is redhead linux)

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0):

Just restart mysqld and mysql.sock will be recreated

```
# service mysqld restart
```

Comment: [root@ensim mysql]# service mysqld restart
egrep: /home/virtual/site22/info/current/mysql: No such file or directory
Stopping MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]

Comment: "egrep: /home/virtual/site22/info/current/mysql:" is that output from service restart?